# How to resolve We are unable to connect to the VM on port 22. Learn more about possible causes of this issue on GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-vpc

I have RHEL instance running on GCP. I was able to connect it using SSH. Later I have installed GUI using the command yum groupinstall "Server with GUI".

After reboot, I am not able to SSH. Getting port 22 error.

Need help

Comment: Does anything show up in the console log of the VM?  Do you think the SSH server has stopped working?

Comment: 1. Go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on `NAME_OF_YOUR_VM` -> at the `VM instance details` find section **Logs** and click on `Serial port 1 (console)` and check if your instance successfully started or there's some error like "No space left".  2. Share your console log at [Hastebin](hastebin.com) and update your question with link. 3. Follow documentation [Troubleshooting SSH](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh) and update your question with your steps, commands and outputs.

Comment: Thanks for resonding.

Comment: https://hastebin.com/ecutibesok.sql

The link as you asked.

Comment: Unfortunately you shared only part of log that contains only limited amount of information. Could you restart your VM and share the log from the moment when VM started.

Comment: Restarted VM. Here is the output: https://hastebin.com/vegacuqupa.json

Comment: Log file looks good. Does your VM have internal and external IP addresses? Have you tried to connect to it via Cloud web UI and via Cloud Shell?

Comment: I have tried to connect it using SSH option and using open in new browser window.

Comment: Try to connect to your VM from Cloud Shell with command like `gcloud compute ssh example-instance --zone=us-central1-a`

Comment: This is the error that I have recieved: ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.ssh) Could not SSH into the instance.  It is possible that your SSH key has not propagated to the instance yet. Try running this command again.  If you st
ill cannot connect, verify that the firewall and instance are set to accept ssh traffic.

Comment: Check you firewall rules as it was recommended at previous step. Also, try to create temporary login/password and connect to VM via serial console as it described in this [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/resolving-getting-locked-out-of-a-compute-engine-85800251890b).

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza Thank you so much. The serial console has resolved the issue. I am able to connect using serial console now.

Comment: Thank you for confirmation. Please accept or upvote my answer if my instructions were helpful for you.

Answer (score 2):

**To solve your issue** you should follow instructions below:

- Go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on `NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE` -> at the `VM instance details` find section **`Logs`** and click on `Serial port 1 (console)` and check if your instance successfully started or if there are some errors.
- Try to create temporary login/password and connect to VM via serial console as it described in this [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/resolving-getting-locked-out-of-a-compute-engine-85800251890b), more information you can find in the documentation [Interacting with the serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console).
- Follow instruction from the documentation [Troubleshooting SSH](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh).

Answer (score 0):

Just add one more firewall rule which can allow ssh. You can name it "default-allow-ssh"

- Network - default
- Priority - 65534
- Direction - Ingress
- Action on match - Allow
- Source filters: IP ranges - 0.0.0.0/0
- Protocols and ports - tcp:22
- Enforcement - Enabled
- Insights - None